# Random share Intent screen

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, 4.2-jelly-bean, share-menu, intents

Sometimes when I'm just casually clicking around in apps or swiping through the OS, I get random Share `Intent` popups. I can usually open it with `ES File Explorer`, `Chrome` or `Dropbox`. It has no indication what the `Intent` is about, so I can't figure it out.

Is there a known cause for this behavior?

Comment: If you go ahead and share whatever it is with an app, what content or data gets shared?

Comment: I'm not sure if I want to find it out that way. It could be malware as far as I know.

Comment: Only a program that's already running on your phone can send the intent. Picking an app from the chooser won't let it do any more than it has already: it just takes the data the app has *already* packaged and saves it (or attaches it to an email, or whatever). Pick something like the file manager where you can examine the saved file and delete it afterwards.

Comment: That would be a bug report, starting from Jellybean (I think), I started getting a lot of these randomly.

If you open it through Gmail, you will see an attachment of the bug report and a description.

Comment: @RaghdHamzeh Next time it shows up, I will open it with an app and review whether it's a bug report.